# Measure on infinite dimesional $L^p$ space relating size in norm to size in measure

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $A$ be a bounded set in an infinite dimensional $L^p$ space. Fix an $\epsilon>0$. Is there a Borel measure $M$ such that
$$ M(B(x,\epsilon)) \geq C, \quad \forall x \in A$$
for some $C>0$ and $B(x,\epsilon)$ being the ball with radius $\epsilon$ around $x$. Clearly, for the same reason as there is no Lebesgue measure on that space, the result can not be true for every $\epsilon>0$: every ball contains infinitely many disjoint balls of radius $\epsilon/4$, if their measures would be bounded below, then the measure of $B(x,\epsilon)$ would be infinite.

If the answer to the above question is negative (which I fear it is): Is there such a Borel measure for the weak topology on $L^p$? In this case, the balls above would be defined using a metric that metrizes weak convergence.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret your question in a way that makes it non-trivial.  Suppose I choose any probability measure on the unit ball $B_1$.  Then taking $\epsilon = 2$, there is a trivial lower bound on the measure of $B(x,2)$ as $x$ ranges over the bounded set $B_1$, namely 1.  Maybe I am not interpreting the quantifiers the way you wanted?

Comment: For the second question, in the weak topology, what do you mean by "ball"?

Comment: Oh, do you want to require that the measure be finite, or $\sigma$-finite, or finite on bounded sets, etc? Otherwise counting measure works.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Thank you for your prompt response. I tried editing the original post to make it more precise. In particular, your example works for $\epsilon=2$ but it might fail for $\epsilon = 1/2$ (or at least it is not obvious to me why it should work). Regarding your question on finiteness: I require the measure to be locally finite (which I guess is implied by the fact that it should be Borel) - in particular $M(A)$ should be finite.

Comment: So you are looking for a condition on $A$ and $\epsilon$ that makes this true?

Comment: @NateEldredge: $A$ and $\epsilon$ are given and I have no particular control over their structure. Hence, I need a measure that works for a given pair ($A$,$\epsilon$). But of course the measure may be specific to that pair. In a finite dimensional space, for example, the Lebesgue measure would work just fine.

Comment: I'm confused, because for some pairs $(A,\epsilon)$ there is certainly no such measure, e.g. the example you mentioned of $A$ being the unit ball and $\epsilon = 1/4$.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Ok, it seems that in the process of making the question more precise it became obvious that what I am looking for does not exist - which is what I feared from the beginning. Sorry, I guess I could have seen that myself. However, there second part of the question concerning the weak topology (not a normed space) is still open, isn't it?